# Using PowerShell to automatically run Library Expansion Option backup

Tags: powershell, scripting, backup

I am trying to think of a good way to write a PowerShell script to run a backup if it had failed. I am not primarily a PowerShell programmer, but networking has been complaining about the number of emails they are getting from LabTech when a backup fails.

- I have the script that checks for a successful backup
- I am wanting to automatically run the backup again if the script above fails
- The LEO backup is what backups our databases
- We use LabTech to create our scripts

Any ideas or help would be great. I have not seen anywhere on Google where someone has tried to do this, so I don't even know if it is possible. Again, I am wanting to automatically run a LEO backup using PowerShell.

Comment: That depends on how your backup tool indicates a failure. If it returns a non-zero exit code you could check `$LastExitCode`. If it throws a (PowerShell-)exception you could use `try..catch`. If it writes a message to a log file, you could parse that log.

Comment: Are there any cmdlets that will allow me to run the backup again? With Backup Exec?

Comment: No, there are no magical `Redo-FailedBackup` cmdlets.

Comment: It doesn't have to redo haha. It just has to run the original backup.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with LEO, but a quick search shows they have a [command line interface](http://www.leo-backup.com/help/source/Html%20help/III/CommandLine.html).  So use powershell to handle all the logic of when and what backup to restore and then call the LEO command line utility from powershell.

You already have a script to check for a successful backup, so add to the logic that if it is not successful to call LEO via command line.  I am not sure where Labtech falls into this.  But your PS script can be set to run as a scheduled task at the appropriate time. Hope that helps.